# Why do I get duplicate entry: com/google/common/base/FinalizableReference.class?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

When I add the Microsoft Azure Mobile Services SDK to my project:

```
compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-services-android-sdk:2.0.2'
```

I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/common/base/FinalizableReference.class
```

What could be the reason and how do I solve this?
I'm guessing I could make some exclude rule for Gradle, but how would that look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running the task `dependencies`, we can see that the `azure-mobile-services-android-sdk` contains two dependencies.

```
\--- com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-services-android-sdk:2.0.2
     +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3
     \--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
```

The class reported as duplicate is from `Guava`. If you are not using it directly, probably another dependency is using it (probably with another version). A possibly fix for this is to exclude Guava from the dependency.

```
compile('com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-services-android-sdk:2.0.2') {
    exclude module: 'guava'
}
```

**Edit:**

Answering your comment, run the `dependencies` task in your project and try to find the other library that is using guava as a dependency (probably an older version of guava).

```
(in your project root folder)
$ cd app
(if you are running on OSX or Linux)
$ ../gradlew dependencies
(if you are running on Windows)
$ ../gradlew.bat dependencies
```

When you figure what dependency have `guava`, exclude it in the same way you did with azure before.

Comment: Actually, spoke too soon. As it turns out, I need the Futures extensions. For that to work, I need to add:
    compile ('com.google.guava:guava:18.0')
and then the error comes back. Any ideas?

Comment: Well... code doesn't format well here in comments. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

it;s because you have two libraries that include the same java class. the command `gradle dependencies` should tell you what it is.

And you have a few choices of how to exclude a dependency:

```
dependencies {

 compile('com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-services-android-sdk:2.0.2') {


   exclude module: 'cglib' //by artifact name

   exclude group: 'org.jmock' //by group

   exclude group: 'com.unwanted', module: 'someLib' //by both name and group

 }

}
```

Comment: When I try the --dependencies command line in Android Studio, I get: "unknown command-line option '--dependencies'". How should I run that?

Comment: @Magnus drop the `--`